# How to manipulate Tiff images with transparency in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, tiff

I am trying to work with TIFF images using C# in an ASP.NET environment. The catch, the images may have transparency, and any time I try to work with a transparent TIFF file I get either an Out of Memory Exception or Parameter is not valid error.

Here are the different ways I've gone about it:

```
string imagename = "Test.tif";
var image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Path-to-File\" + imagename);
```

OR

```
Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(@"C:\Path-to-File\" + imagename);
```

I've tried throwing it into a filestream and still receive errors. The TIFF files are coming from Photoshop, and I've definitely narrowed down transparency as the culprit.

[This link does mention that the Image class does not support transparency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stf701f5%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Looking for any sort of guidance...this shouldn't be as difficult as I'm finding.

Comment: According to the docs TIFF is supproted. Do you receive an error?

Comment: As stated in my original post, I receive "Out of Memory" Exception. Although the docs state TIFF is supported, it specifically calls out Transparency as not being supported.

Comment: Sorry I missed that.   =P Do you have a sample image? And did you see this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6069439/426422

Comment: No worries! Image attached. I noticed in the properties of this image that the bit depth is 40, whereas a non-transparent image of the same kind is set to 32. Wondering if this has anything to do with this. Yes I did see that link, I need to use TIFF for Printing purposes, PNG is compressed.

Comment: From what I am seeing a TIFF is a bitmap and both are great for printing. Is there a reason you cannot open it in a bitmap and print it from that? Also I think imgur converted your tiff into a png.

Comment: PNG uses lossless compression. Have you checked in the options presented when you save in Photoshop that it is set to save in IBM PC byte order, just in case? I assume your image is no larger than 32767 pixels in either dimension. Maybe an alternative like [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) would work better for you.

Comment: The printer I am working with needs TIFF which is a standard in Print Production. Not seeing the IBM PC byte order option. Image is 400 x 400. I'll look at FreeImage...

Comment: You might need to use "Save As..." to get the byte order option. 400px x 400px isn't very large - are you referring to the pixels per inch rather than the pixel dimensions? (We get a lot of designers asking for 300ppi images instead of telling us what size they are going to use an image; I am sometimes *tempted* to give them a 1 pixel image at 300ppi.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Andrew Morton suggesting FreeImage, it ended up leading me to the Magick.NET library.

Ultimately FreeImage was near impossible to get to work in a C# program using current versions of Visual Studio, thus from some digging I found [Magick.NET](http://www.imagemagick.org/index.php) which after a quick search in NuGet, was very easy to install and get going.

Here is what I did:

- Search for Magick in NuGet and select the desired architecture (x64 or x86)

Note: If selecting x64, the build settings for your project must be set to this same architecture otherwise you will get a failure such as:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Magick.NET.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

- Familiarize yourself with the basics in this [documentation](https://magick.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Convert%20image)

That's it! Here is the code I used to get it working:

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(@"C:\FolderPathToFile\OriginalFile.tif"))
{
    image.Write(@"C:\FolderPathToFile\FinalOutput.png");
}
```